# Check and update if the field doesn't exists in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a few documents in the collection `orders` where `is_show` is already set with value `true/false` for the new documents .

Now what I want is , for the past documents , it should insert the key
 `is_show` with value `false` for particular order type . For that 
I have written the query as shown below :

```
db.getCollection("orders").update({"order_type":1}, {$set: {"is_show": false}}, false, true)
```

But some how it is adding `is_show` false for the new as well as old documents .

so how can I modify the query to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`$exists`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query operator to check whether the document contains that field or not

```
db.getCollection("orders").update(
  { "order_type": 1, "is_show": { "$exists": false }},
  { "$set": { "is_show": false }},
  { "multi": true }
)
```